# AutoValue Gson type adapter for a Map<String, List<Obj>>

Tags: android, gson, auto-value

I'm trying to find a way to use [AutoValue](https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-gson) to deserialize a JSON obj to a Java class (which is also Parcelable)

The JSON response is usually in the form of,

```
{
  "varKey1": {
    "occupations": [
      {
        "value": "val1",
        "name": "name1"
      },
      {
        "value": "val2",
        "name": "name2"
      }
    ]
  },
  "varKey2": {
    "occupations": [
      {
        "value": "val1",
        "name": "name1"
      },
      {
        "value": "val2",
        "name": "name2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

where `varKey1` and `varKey2` are strings that are not fixed/predefined so could have any value.

I'm having difficulty figuring out what the typeAdapter for this should look like though with AutoValue Gson, and any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Type typeOfHashMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<Obj>>>() { }.getType();
Map<String, List<Obj>> newMap = gson.fromJson(json, typeOfHashMap);
have you tried this?
also, you will have to add the type adapter to your class 
public static TypeAdapter<MovieWrapper> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
        return new AutoValue_MovieWrapper.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
    }

Answer (score 5):

As far I understand how AutoValue and AutoValue: Gson Extension work, you cannot deserialize `Map<String, List<Obj>>` from the given JSON by using these tools only, since they are just simple source code generators. The latter even states *that creates a **simple** Gson TypeAdapterFactory for each AutoValue annotated object*.

Taking the given JSON and `Map<String, List<Obj>>` into account, you can:

- ... have `Map<String, Wrapper>` where the wrapper class contains `List<Obj>` (and declare a type adapter for each `@AutoValue`-annotated) class, thus having a dumb intermediate mediator object named *`Wrapper`*.
- ... implement a custom type adapter that cannot be generated by AutoValue: Gson Extension.

The 2nd option is not hard as it may sound, and can help to work around when the AutoValue extension cannot generate type adapters for other sophisticated cases.

#### Declare necessary type tokens

```java
final class TypeTokens {

    private TypeTokens() {
    }

    static final TypeToken<Map<String, List<Obj>>> mapStringToObjListTypeToken = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<Obj>>>() {
    };

    static final TypeToken<List<Obj>> objListTypeTypeToken = new TypeToken<List<Obj>>() {
    };

}
```

#### Implement a custom type adapter factory

Gson type adapter factories are used to resolve (and bind) a particular type adapter and, if necessary, bind the adapter to Gson instances to deal with any Gson configuration.

```java
final class CustomTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private static final TypeAdapterFactory customTypeAdapterFactory = new CustomTypeAdapterFactory();

    static TypeAdapterFactory getCustomTypeAdapterFactory() {
        return customTypeAdapterFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if ( typeToken.getType().equals(mapStringToObjListTypeToken.getType()) ) {
            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            final TypeAdapter<T> castTypeAdapter = (TypeAdapter) getMapStringToObjectListTypeAdapter(gson);
            return castTypeAdapter;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Note that the only responsibility of the factory is returning a special type adapter that can skip the wrappers in your JSON. If any other type is requested to the factory, returning `null` is safe and lets Gson try to pick another type adapter best-match (built-ins or your configuration).

#### Implement the type adapter

This is actually what Auto Value: Gson Extension seems not can do. Since type adapters are essentially stream-oriented, they may look too low-level, but this is the best Gson can do because streaming is a very efficient technique, and it's also used in what Auto Value: Gson Extension generates.

```java
final class MapStringToObjectListTypeAdapter
        extends TypeAdapter<Map<String, List<Obj>>> {

    private final TypeAdapter<List<Obj>> wrapperAdapter;

    private MapStringToObjectListTypeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<List<Obj>> wrapperAdapter) {
        this.wrapperAdapter = wrapperAdapter;
    }

    static TypeAdapter<Map<String, List<Obj>>> getMapStringToObjectListTypeAdapter(final Gson gson) {
        return new MapStringToObjectListTypeAdapter(gson.getAdapter(objListTypeTypeToken));
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Map<String, List<Obj>> value)
            throws IOException {
        if ( value == null ) {
            // nulls must be written
            out.nullValue();
        } else {
            out.beginObject();
            for ( final Entry<String, List<Obj>> e : value.entrySet() ) {
                out.name(e.getKey());
                out.beginObject();
                out.name("occupations");
                wrapperAdapter.write(out, e.getValue());
                out.endObject();
            }
            out.endObject();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, List<Obj>> read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        // if there's JSON null, then just return nothing
        if ( in.peek() == NULL ) {
            return null;
        }
        // or read the map
        final Map<String, List<Obj>> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        // expect the { token
        in.beginObject();
        // and read recursively until } is occurred
        while ( in.peek() != END_OBJECT ) {
            // this is the top-most level where varKey# occur
            final String key = in.nextName();
            in.beginObject();
            while ( in.peek() != END_OBJECT ) {
                final String wrapperName = in.nextName();
                switch ( wrapperName ) {
                case "occupations":
                    // if this is the "occupations" property, delegate the parsing to an underlying type adapter
                    result.put(key, wrapperAdapter.read(in));
                    break;
                default:
                    // or just skip the value (or throw an exception, up to you)
                    in.skipValue();
                    break;
                }
            }
            in.endObject();
        }
        in.endObject();
        return result;
    }

}
```

#### Auto Value-generated factory

Unlike the custom type adapter factory, some of Gson type adapter factories are already generated and can deal with `abstract` classes like what `Obj` is (at least in your source code, not the generated one).

```
@GsonTypeAdapterFactory
abstract class GeneratedTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public static TypeAdapterFactory getGeneratedTypeAdapterFactory() {
        return new AutoValueGson_GeneratedTypeAdapterFactory();
    }

}
```

#### How it's used

```
private static void dump(final Map<?, ?> map) {
    for ( final Entry<?, ?> e : map.entrySet() ) {
        out.print(e.getKey());
        out.print(" => ");
        out.println(e.getValue());
    }
}

...

final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getGeneratedTypeAdapterFactory())
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getCustomTypeAdapterFactory())
        .create();
dump(gson.fromJson(json, mapStringToObjListTypeToken.getType()));
```

gives the following output:

> varKey1 => [Obj{name=name1, value=val1}, Obj{name=name2, value=val2}]
>   varKey2 => [Obj{name=name1, value=val1}, Obj{name=name2, value=val2}]

If you use wrappers only from the first option, then the output is as follows:

> varKey1 => Wrapper{occupations=[Obj{name=name1, value=val1}, Obj{name=name2, value=val2}]}
>   varKey2 => Wrapper{occupations=[Obj{name=name1, value=val1}, Obj{name=name2, value=val2}]}